# chat and back to top in the right bottom corner

Tags: placement, back-button, chatbots

I can't find any good examples from the web where chat box button and back to top button are both placed in the right bottom corner.I have to place both of them and I don't know what would be the best solution?Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

For questions like this I recommend the Nielsen Norman Group, as it's a great source of research-based usability guidelines.

They also covered both back-to-top buttons and chats:

- [Back-to-Top Button Design Guidelines](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/back-to-top/)
- [The User Experience of Customer-Service Chat: 20 Guidelines](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/chat-ux/)

It appears that they should indeed both be placed on the right side of the page.